# Efficiently find the indices of shared values (with repeats) between two large arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

##### Problem description

Let's take this simple array set

```
            # 0,1,2,3,4,5
a = np.array([1,1,3,4,6])
b = np.array([6,6,1,3])
```

From these two arrays I want to get the indices of all possible matches. So for number `1` we get `0,2`  and `1,2`, with the complete output looking like:

```
0,2 # 1
1,2 # 1
2,3 # 3
4,0 # 6
4,1 # 6
```

Note that the arrays are (not yet) sorted neither do they only contain unique elements - two conditions often assumed in other answers (see bottom). The above example is very small, however, I have to apply this to ~40K element arrays.

---

#### Tried approaches

###### 1.Python loop approach

```
indx = []
for i, aval in enumerate(a):
    for j, bval in enumerate(b):
        if aval == bval:
            indx.append([i,j])
# [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 0], [4, 1]]
```

###### 2.Python dict approach

```
adict = defaultdict(list)
bdict = defaultdict(list)
for i, aval in enumerate(a): adict[aval].append(i)
for j, bval in enumerate(b): bdict[bval].append(j)

for val, a_positions in adict.items():
    for b_position in bdict[val]:
        for a_position in a_positions:
            print(a_position, b_position)
```

###### 3.Numpy where

`print(np.where(a.reshape(-1,1) ==  b))`

###### 4. Polars dataframes

Converting it to a dataframe and then using [Polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars)

```
import polars as pl
a = pl.DataFrame( {'x': a, 'apos':list(range(len(a)))} )
b = pl.DataFrame( {'x': b, 'apos':list(range(len(b)))} )
a.join(b, how='inner', on='x')
```

---

###### "Big data"

On "big" data using Polars seems the fastest now with around 0.02 secs. I'm suprised that creating DataFrames first and then joining them is faster than any other approach I could come up with so curious if there is any other way to beat it :)

```
a = np.random.randint(0,1000, 40000)
b = np.random.randint(0,1000, 40000)
```

Using the above data:

> 1. python loop: 218s
> 2. python dict: 0.03s
> 3. numpy.where: 4.5s
> 4. polars: 0.02s

---

##### How related questions didn't solve this

- [Return common element indices between two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333593/return-common-element-indices-between-two-numpy-arrays), only returns the indexes of matchesin one of the arrays, not both
- [Find indices of common values in two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653441/find-indices-of-common-values-in-two-arrays.), returns the matching indices of A with B and B with A, but not the paired indices (see example)

Very surprised a DataFrame library is currently the fastest, so curious to see if there are other approaches to beat this speed :) Everything is fine, cython, numba, pythran etc.

Comment: Are your "big data" realistic? I mean: are integer values always positive, bounded and small? Such information can help a lot to design faster algorithms.

Comment: @JérômeRichard hey! They actually can be any signed integer, so could be negative too

Comment: You can speed up the dict approach a little (25% in my computer) by remplacing the 2 for loops by `indx += list(itertools.product(a_positions, bdict[val]))`

Comment: What time does the dict solution take if you remove the word `print`? I suspect more time is spent on *printing* the pairs than on *finding* them. Also, did you put that code into a function or was it in global scope and thus suffered from slow global variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** this post is now superseded by the faster alternative sort-based solution.

The dict based approach is an algorithmically efficient solution compared to others (I guess Polars should use a similar approach). However, the **overhead of CPython** make it a bit slow. You can speed it up a bit using **Numba**. Here is an implementation:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from numba.typed.typeddict import Dict
from numba.typed.typedlist import ListType
from numba.typed.typedlist import List

IntList = ListType(nb.int32)

@nb.njit('(int32[:], int32[:])')
def numba_dict_based_compute(a, b):
    adict = Dict.empty(nb.int32, IntList)
    bdict = Dict.empty(nb.int32, IntList)

    for i, val in enumerate(a):
        if val in adict: adict[val].append(i)
        else: adict[val] = List([nb.int32(i)])

    for i, val in enumerate(b):
        if val in bdict: bdict[val].append(i)
        else: bdict[val] = List([nb.int32(i)])

    count = 0

    for val, a_positions in adict.items():
        if val not in bdict:
            continue
        b_positions = bdict[val]
        count += len(a_positions) * len(b_positions)

    result = np.empty((count, 2), dtype=np.int32)
    cur = 0

    for val, a_positions in adict.items():
        if val not in bdict:
            continue
        for b_position in bdict[val]:
            for a_position in a_positions:
                result[cur, 0] = a_position
                result[cur, 1] = b_position
                cur += 1

    return result

result = numba_dict_based_compute(a.astype(np.int32), b.astype(np.int32))
```

Note that computing in-place the value is a bit faster than storing them (and pre-compute the size of the array). However, if nothing is done in the loop, Numba can completely optimize it out and the benchmark would be biased. Alternatively, printing values is so slow that is would also biased the benchmark. Note also that the implementation assumes the numbers are 32-bit ones. A 64 bit implementation can be trivially implemented by replacing 32-bit types by 64-bit ones though it decreases the performance.

This solution is about twice faster on my machine though it is a bit verbose and not very easy to read. The performance of the operation is mainly bounded by the speed of dictionary lookups. This implementation is a bit faster than the one of polars on my machine.

Here are timings:

```
Naive python loop:   >100_000   ms
Numpy where:            3_451   ms
Python dict:               24.7 ms
Polars:                    12.3 ms
This implementation:       11.3 ms    (takes 13.2 ms on 64-bit values)
```

Comment: Interesting! Didn't know numba also had this "defaultdict" possibility

Comment: Great answer. In my installation, this implementation is about 18 times faster than the "Python dict".

Comment: When I try this with `a,b = np.array([5,0], dtype = np.int32), np.array([1, 3], dtype = np.int32)` it will throw a `KeyError`. It needs `if val in bdict:` before every `bdict[val]` I suppose? Or perhaps just not add to `bdict` if it was not present in `adict`, will check that too

Comment: @CodeNoob Indeed, I added missing checks. It turns out this is faster than not adding items in adict. This is certainly due to the fact that this does not append in practice on the "bid data" test (so the processor can *predict* the conditional jumps and be faster).

Comment: @phi Did you remove the printing in the "Python dict" solution?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I assume you did change the "Python dict" solution? Can you share the code as you used it in your benchmark? (Or preferably the whole benchmark.)

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, as it would bias the benchmark to use printing code. I used `pass` instead of `print(a_position, b_position)`. CPython does not optimize such a code (at least not on my machine). No printing for the Numpy solution: I just stored the result in a variable. And nothing more. For the timings, I use magic IPython commands like `%%timeit`. It would be better if the OP could precise what function is actually computed in the nested loops (since storing all combinations is far from being efficient and may benefit to some implementations).

Comment: Did you put it into a function, so that it benefits from using local variables?

Comment: @KellyBundy No, I did like the OP. But, good catch: this can impact performance. That being said, I just tested on another machine and it is actually a bit slower in a function: 27 ms (global) VS 29 ms (in a function). It only impact the dict-based and the naive loop-based code. Other are left unchanged.

Comment: Are you using PyPy or some other Python implementation other than CPython? In CPython, it should definitely be faster in a function.

Comment: I tried it myself now and in a function it was [factor 1.6 *faster*](https://tio.run/##7VFLasMwEN3rFLOLDK5xSVeGniQUM7blVEE/JLmQ07sjW0mctJTSdbWw0cz7jN64c3y3Zj/Po7caotRCRpDaWR9hECNOKrap6gHD0ma5aSbtzqloHFu4vVVK9FFaEx4EBtlHxhBeCVt5NIPVy0@ayOvyua7rEl7oWxes@w2IkS6Mk@k5ltAVDQM6mFyIvfHkSoZYLN3ux@5oPcgS8AMVSAOC3iY8RsGxaFbhQ@q9VeicMAOXN9qJJvhCo5lWx0O3pZ1uNCqTX@tskDkxsxpVMgodeH7UBd5dkQm4SiflG@qCxDvkxuEemo7DEBhLpDZhKeyj4PvsHGtKK@2b56GvcS9X59NedqnaAOzKDIUnItKCvlP4X9CfFrRJ@6hsh6p5SHuePwE) (that's CPython 3.7, but I got the same factor on 3.10.2 as well).

Comment: @KellyBundy Strange. I just tested on the initial machine and I got a <2% speed up. I use 3.8.1 built with MSVC on Windows and a i5-9600KF processor. In fact, this overhead is smaller than the one due to the environment variation: running the same code again on a rebooted machine now gives me a ~3% slower execution (typically due to random values, ASRL, background programs, and possibly room temperature -- my country suffer from a heat wave ^^").

Comment: Is that from running my program? If not, what results do you get with that?

Comment: @KellyBundy Here is a raw execution from a clean IPython new run: https://pastebin.com/R0bSwpBz (the timing change a bit when IPython is run again but the difference is quite small: something like 2%). Ha! with your program results are pretty different. The IPython result match with the one in a function so it should not use globals internally. See: https://pastebin.com/zBuY9jqt

Comment: I'm not familiar with `%%timeit`. Are you sure it doesn't put the code into a function (like Python's `timeit` module does)?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative completely-different solution is to **sort the array** and retrieve the locations of the sorted array with `np.argsort`, then get the sorted value, and then walk in lockstep over the two set of locations sorted by value. This last operation can be (again) implemented efficiently in Numba or Cython. It can be actually split in two part: the one finding slices in `a` and `b` matching to the same value (similar to a merge operation), and one doing the actual cartesian product for each matching slices. Splitting this in two steps enable the second one (which is expensive) to be computed in parallel if possible (and in-place if possible too). The complexity of finding the matching offsets is `O(n log n)` with Numpy (one can reach the theoretical optimal `O(n)` time using a *radix sort*).

Here is the resulting implementation:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

# Support both 32-bit and 64-bit integers
@nb.njit(['(int64[::1],int64[::1],int64[::1],int64[::1])', '(int64[::1],int64[::1],int32[::1],int32[::1])'], debug=True)
def find_matching_offsets(a_positions, b_positions, a_sorted_values, b_sorted_values):
    n, m = a_positions.size, b_positions.size
    result = np.empty((n, 4), dtype=np.int32)

    a_pos, b_pos, cur = 0, 0, 0
    while a_pos < n and b_pos < m:
        a_val = a_sorted_values[a_pos]
        b_val = b_sorted_values[b_pos]

        if a_val < b_val:
            a_pos += 1
            continue

        if a_val > b_val:
            b_pos += 1
            continue

        a_end = n
        for i in range(a_pos + 1, n):
            if a_sorted_values[i] != a_val:
                a_end = i
                break

        b_end = m
        for i in range(b_pos + 1, m):
            if b_sorted_values[i] != b_val:
                b_end = i
                break

        result[cur, 0] = a_pos
        result[cur, 1] = a_end
        result[cur, 2] = b_pos
        result[cur, 3] = b_end
        cur += 1

        a_pos = a_end
        b_pos = b_end

    return result[:cur]

@nb.njit(['(int64[::1],int64[::1],int32[:,::1])'], parallel=True)
def do_cartesian_product(a_positions, b_positions, offsets):
    size = 0
    cur = 0
    result_offsets = np.empty(offsets.shape[0], dtype=np.int32)

    # Compute the size of the output
    for i in range(offsets.shape[0]):
        a_pos, a_end, b_pos, b_end = offsets[i]
        assert a_end > a_pos and b_end > b_pos
        result_offsets[cur] = size
        size += (a_end - a_pos) * (b_end - b_pos)
        cur += 1

    assert size > 0
    result = np.empty((size, 2), dtype=np.int32)

    # Generate the output in parallel (or in-place if possible)
    for i in nb.prange(offsets.shape[0]):
        a_pos, a_end, b_pos, b_end = offsets[i]
        offset = result_offsets[i]
        local_cur = 0
        for j in range(a_pos, a_end):
            for k in range(b_pos, b_end):
                local_offset = offset + local_cur
                result[local_offset, 0] = a_positions[j]
                result[local_offset, 1] = b_positions[k]
                local_cur += 1

    return result

def sorted_based_compute(a, b):
    a_positions = np.argsort(a)
    b_positions = np.argsort(b)
    a_sorted_values = a[a_positions]
    b_sorted_values = b[b_positions]
    offsets = find_matching_offsets(a_positions, b_positions, a_sorted_values, b_sorted_values)
    return do_cartesian_product(a_positions, b_positions, offsets)
```

This solution is faster than the previous one and certainly reach the limit of with what is possible with Numpy/Numba (without making additional assumptions on the input). Here is the performance results (on my 6-core machine):

```
Python dict:                        24.7 ms
Polars:                             12.3 ms
Dict-based Numba version:           11.3 ms
Sort-based Numpy+Numba version:      5.0 ms  <----
```

Note that ~60% of the time is spent in the `argsort` functions and the rest is basically the cartesian product. It can theoretically be improved using a parallel sort but AFAIK this is not possible with Numpy yet (and pretty hard to do in Numba).